# How can I fix three.js loading issues?

Tags: three.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJv59.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoZ4I.png)

I am having issues adding the three.js libraries. Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you have three.js file at the path you specified?

Comment: for more information read https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, you are missing to define an import map in your `index.html`. Do it like so:

```js
<!-- Import maps polyfill -->
<!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
                "three": "./three/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can then change the `THREE` import to:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

The error is actually produced in your example files since `OrbitControls` and `GLTFLoader` use the bare import specifier `three`. So without an import map, the browser can't resolve the specifier.

Comment: Important to note that (currently) import maps are not supported in Firefox nor Safari, in case those platforms are relevant to OP's use-case. https://caniuse.com/import-maps

Comment: The above code snippet contains a shim that should make things work in those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me. It uses CDNs, but at least it works (also for firebox):

```html
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.0/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
          "imports": {
            "three": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.144.0/build/three.module",
            "three/": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.144.0/"
          }
        }
    </script>
<script src="szene2.js" type="module">  </script>
```

In your javascript:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader';
```